# Conditional Formatting COUNTIFS (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-custom-function

I'd like column P to be highlighted when:

- A contains "x"
- E contains "approved"
- O < today (date has passed)
- P and Q are blank

My formula doesn't work:

`=COUNTIFS(A6:A, "x", E6:E, "approved", O6:O, "<"&today(), P6:P, "", Q6:Q, "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one by entering it into desired cell at 6th row and expanding the range (eg. `P6:P`):

```
=COUNTIFS(A6, "x", E6, "approved", O6, "<"&today(), P6, "", Q6, "")
```

Comment: this works perfectly!! user0, you are the BEST! thank you